# Ideal location to practice soldering

Tags: soldering, hobbyist

Sounds like a stupid question, but really hasn't been asked before, or I haven't found a post about it. Either way, here it is:

I bought a soldering iron recently and am looking for a place in my house to do my soldering. Of course the first thing in my mind would be to solder in the basement or garage and as close to a window/outdoors with good circulation, however I plan on working with arduino boards and would like to everything in my upstairs "computer room" near my gadgets. Do you think opening up my window in my room and having a fan suck out the fumes aimed at the window would be suffice to be safe, or should I stick with the basement/garage idea. Let me know on your thoughts.

Comment: I hear Maui is nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Near a window with a fan sucking the fumes out the window would be better fume technique than most non-professionals would use.  Unless you're particularly sensitive, or asthmatic it should be more than good enough for the low volume infrequent soldering you'll be doing.  Personally, I'd be more concerned about the iron as a fire hazard.

Comment: I live in AZ, soldering with the window open is not all that feasible ;)

Comment: Can't tell you how many old electronics techs, who do plenty of (periodic) soldering, doing their work in tiny unventilated closets.  I guess all the young ones just die ;)

Comment: haha! I started soldering when I was rather young, 11-12, and made myself super paranoid about it.  It has stuck with me all these years.

Comment: Also, if a day of soldering is planned, drinking plenty of fluids will abate most of the irritation in your from inhaling the fumes. Tea works for me as its give your eyes a rest periodically too while you make it. Too many times has a "quick" solder job turned into an afternoon of attempting to repair everything on the shelf. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've been soldering in poorly ventilated rooms for years and I'm still alive.

I think the sociopathy is unrelated, probably related to age or unprotected contact with Javascript.

Comment: hahaha where did the javascript comment come from?lol

Comment: Bitter experience!

Comment: Use JQuery. 8')

Answer (score 0):

You need good circulation. Flux is noxious when it burns (and only *slightly* less so when not burning), and you *need* to use flux.

Comment: In your experience, where do you do your soldering, if done at home? with that in mind, My scenario in my room wouldn't be ideal because of the lack of circulation.

Comment: It's not _that_ bad, it's only a small plume of smoke and it doesn't linger as badly as tobacco smoke. Computer room with open window is fine,  although keep it away from piles of flammable paper and don't drip solder on the carpet.

Comment: I do it in my living room, over a sheet of glass. But I have a small apartment so ventilation is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Good circulation and a fume extractor/absorber.  I use one of these guys:  [http://www.amazon.com/Weller-WSA350-Bench-Smoke-Absorber/dp/B000EM74SK/ref=pd_sim_sbs_hi_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EM74SK)

There are also smaller ones available that can be put right above the work area to absorb more: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00012YSDW/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00012YSDW)

Carbon activated filter takes a lot of the fumes and chemicals out of the air.  Also helps to turn on a ceiling fan, or your HVACs fan and get good air moving around.